# How can I add a loopback and immediately set its source output volume?

Tags: pulseaudio

I've figured out how to split my audio into things for my own speakers, things for broadcast (to a video chat or other stream), and things for both.

This is what I have so far in `~/.pulse/default.pa`:

```
# Swap channels of workstation speakers
load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=reversed-speakers sink_properties='device.description="Reversed speakers"' master=alsa_output.usb-0c76_USB_PnP_Audio_Device-00.iec958-stereo channels=2 master_channel_map=front-left,front-right channel_map=front-right,front-left

# Virtual sinks for myself, broadcast, and both
load-module module-null-sink sink_name=for-me sink_properties='device.description="For me"'
load-module module-null-sink sink_name=for-broadcast sink_properties='device.description="For broadcast"'
load-module module-null-sink sink_name=for-all sink_properties='device.description="For all"'

# Split for-all to me and to broadcast
load-module module-loopback source=for-all.monitor sink=for-me
load-module module-loopback source=for-all.monitor sink=for-broadcast

# Point the microphones at the broadcast
load-module module-loopback source=alsa_input.usb-046d_C922_Pro_Stream_Webcam_266FB1AF-02.iec958-stereo sink=for-broadcast
load-module module-loopback source=alsa_input.usb-0c76_USB_PnP_Audio_Device-00.iec958-stereo sink=for-broadcast
load-module module-loopback source=alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo sink=for-broadcast

# Point everything aimed at me to the (flipped) speakers
load-module module-loopback source=for-me.monitor sink=reversed-speakers

# By default things should go just to me
set-default-sink for-me

# By default things should get the for-broadcast input
set-default-source for-broadcast.monitor
```

This works great -- all I have to do is point a particular application at either "for broadcast" or "for all" to broadcast it, depending whether I also want to hear it or not.

What I haven't figured out is how to set the volumes at startup time. I want the source output volumes of the "for me" and "for broadcast" loopbacks to be at -6dB and -12dB respectively.

I can set these manually in (for example) pavucontrol, but on restart *all* loopbacks' source output volumes end up at the same low volume (I don't recall off hand whether it was -6 or -12).

I can't find any option to set this volume at the same time as `load-module module-loopback`, and I don't know how to get the loopback's index immediately after creating it in my `default.pa` file in order to run `set-source-output-volume` on it.

Comment: Side question: with this kind of setup should I also set up the echo cancellation module? How would I configure that if so? Or would that somehow be configured for me?...

Comment: I've noticed this takes quite a bit of CPU even when there's no sound being played. 12% of one CPU constantly. Maybe this isn't a good idea after all...